# What is the lifetime of the descriptor of a generated protobuf message?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, proto

I am using Protobuf 2 in my project. I want to use `DynamicMessageFactory` to create messages at run-time. `DynamicMessageFactory`requires a `Descriptor*`. I am passing `Descriptor*` of a mutable message of a generated class. The documentation says that `Descriptor` must outlive `DynamicMessageFactory` which in turn should outlive the message generated by the factory.

What is the lifetime of the descriptor of a generated class? Is it static member of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptors for generated-code / compiled-in message classes live forever, so you should be good.

But if your types are complied-in, then there's no reason to use `DynamicMessageFactory`. Dynamic messages are much slower than generated code, and generated code supports the whole dynamic interface in addition to the generated interface. You could use [the generated factory](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#MessageFactory.generated_factory.details) instead to get instances of generated messages. Or, an even cleaner strategy is to get the message's prototype by calling `MyType::default_instance()`, and then pass around that pointer rather than passing around the descriptor.

If you need to mix some dynamic types with some generated types, also consider using [`DynamicMessageFactory::SetDelegateToGeneratedFactory()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message#DynamicMessageFactory.SetDelegateToGeneratedFactory.details).